# Springfox global response header

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

In my spring boot rest API, I'm sending back a unique request id header "x-request-id" for every response (irrespective of the method) for every endpoint. I can add this using something like this:

```
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(
            code = 200, 
            message = "Successful status response", 
            responseHeaders = {
                    @ResponseHeader(
                            name = "x-request-id", 
                            description = "auto generated unique request id", 
                            response = String.class)})
})
```

This works fine and I can see it in the Swagger UI. However, doing this for every endpoint is a tedious + maintenance problem. I'm looking to do this globally but the [Springfox documentation](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-swagger2-with-spring-mvc-and-spring-boot) only shows about global response message using .globalResponseMessage option - I can't find anything for global response headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up creating an annotation to handle this:

```
package com.abc.xyz.api.docs.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import io.swagger.annotations.ResponseHeader;

import com.abc.xyz.api.constants.ApiConstants;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(
            code = 200, 
            message = "Successful status response",
            responseHeaders = {
                    @ResponseHeader(
                            name = ApiConstants.REQUESTIDHEADER,
                            description = ApiConstants.REQUESTIDDESCRIPTION, 
                            response = String.class)}),
    @ApiResponse(
            code = 401, 
            message = "Successful status response",
            responseHeaders = {
                    @ResponseHeader(
                            name = ApiConstants.REQUESTIDHEADER,
                            description = ApiConstants.REQUESTIDDESCRIPTION, 
                            response = String.class)}),
    @ApiResponse(
            code = 403, 
            message = "Successful status response",
            responseHeaders = {
                    @ResponseHeader(
                            name = ApiConstants.REQUESTIDHEADER,
                            description = ApiConstants.REQUESTIDDESCRIPTION, 
                            response = String.class)}),
    @ApiResponse(
            code = 404, 
            message = "Successful status response",
            responseHeaders = {
                    @ResponseHeader(
                            name = ApiConstants.REQUESTIDHEADER,
                            description = ApiConstants.REQUESTIDDESCRIPTION, 
                            response = String.class)}),
    }
)
public @interface RequestIdMethod {};
```

With this, I can add this as a marker annotation in front of my methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/heartbeat", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestIdMethod
public Heartbeat checkHeartbeat() {
    return new Heartbeat(status);
}
```

It is not great because I need to repeat the entire @ApiResponse annotation block for every http return code (obviously there could be other return codes but I only covered the default codes shown by Springfox). Would have been better if there was a way to parameterize the entire @ApiResponse block.

Comment: Hi Soumen, I added an answer to this very old thread... hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party here, but I did find a way to globally add a header to every response using reflection (might not be required but turned out to be the easiest way for me to get EVERY response. You can also check for all `ApiResponses` annotations but some were added implicitly and therefore left out with that approach).

```
@Component
@Order(SwaggerPluginSupport.SWAGGER_PLUGIN_ORDER + 10)
public class RequestIdResponseHeaderPlugin implements OperationBuilderPlugin {

  @Override
  public boolean supports(DocumentationType documentationType) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void apply(OperationContext operationContext) {
    try {
      // we use reflection here since the operationBuilder.build() method would lead to different operation ids
      // and we only want to access the private field 'responseMessages' to add the request-id header to it
      Field f = operationContext.operationBuilder().getClass().getDeclaredField("responseMessages");
      f.setAccessible(true);
      Set<ResponseMessage> responseMessages = (Set<ResponseMessage>) f.get(operationContext.operationBuilder());
      responseMessages.forEach(message -> {
        int code = message.getCode();
        Map<String, Header> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("my-header-name", new Header(null, null, new ModelRef("string")));
        ResponseMessage responseMessage = new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(code).headersWithDescription(map).build();
        operationContext.operationBuilder().responseMessages(Collections.singleton(responseMessage));
      });
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Found this way after looking into the method `responseMessages()` of the operation-builder. It internally merges response-headers based on the status-code and the logic itself will simply add headers to existing response-headers.

Hope it helps someone since it does not require you to annotate every single endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Docket configuration to include the Global header on every API. Hope this helps.

```java
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .contact(new Contact("My Support", null, "My Email"))
            .description("My Description")
            .licenseUrl("My License")
            .title("My Title")
            .termsOfServiceUrl("My Terms and Conditions")
            .version("My Version")
            .build())
    .globalOperationParameters(Collections.singletonList(new ParameterBuilder()
            .name("x-request-id")
            .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
            .parameterType("header")
            .required(false)
            .build()))
    .select()
    .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/user*))
    .build()
    .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
    .directModelSubstitute(LocalDateTime.class, String.class);
```

Comment: this adds a global request header. Not a response header. Are you able to add a global response header?